# Testing for disappearance of element using react testing library fails

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

I am trying to test disappearance of dialog box when user clicks "cancel" button on my dialog box using the following test:

```
it("clicking on cancel hides the confirmation dialog", async() => {
    render(<ConfirmationDialog />);
    const cancelButton = screen.getByText("Cancel");
    fireEvent.click(cancelButton);
    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.queryByText(/Cancel/i));
    expect(screen.queryByText(/Cancel/i)).toBeNull();
  });
```

But the above code throws an error :
**TypeError: MutationObserver is not a constructor**

```
  24 |     const cancelButton = screen.getByText("Cancel");
  25 |     fireEvent.click(cancelButton);
> 26 |     await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.queryByText(/Cancel/i));
     |           ^
  27 |     expect(screen.queryByText(/Cancel/i)).toBeNull();
  28 |   });
  29 | });
```

Can someone help me understanding this issue as I am new to testing library. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use jest? (make sure all latest versions are installed)

Comment: @true_gler yes I am using Jest + react Testing Library for all of my React Tests

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) in your test :

- Add @sheerun/mutationobserver-shim package to your project
- in setupTests.js (or [other Jest configuration file](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration)), add the following code :

```js
import MutationObserver from '@sheerun/mutationobserver-shim';
window.MutationObserver = MutationObserver;
```

Your UI framework certainly depends on it.

There may be other way to mock [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), this is how I do it but it may not be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this according to: https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/477

```
npm install jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen
```

or

```
yarn add -D jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen
```

and then set it via env cli param

```
 "scripts": {
        ...
       "test": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
       ...
    }
```